# Search some text in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, search

How can I search a word in a PHP array?

I try `in_array`, but it find just exactly the same values.

```
<?php
$namesArray = array('Peter', 'Joe', 'Glenn', 'Cleveland');  
if (in_array('Peter Parker', $namesArray)) {echo "There is.";}
else {echo "There is not.";}
```

I want this instance to return true. How can I do it? Is there any function?

Snippet: https://glot.io/snippets/ek086tekl0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to say I like the simplicity of Gre_gor's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40428438/4982088), but for a more dynamic method you can also use `array_filter()`:

```
function my_array_search($array, $needle){
  $matches = array_filter($array, function ($haystack) use ($needle){
    // return stripos($needle, $haystack) !== false; make the function case insensitive
    return strpos($needle, $haystack) !== false;
  });

  return empty($matches) ? false : $matches;
}


$namesArray = ['Peter', 'Glenn', 'Meg', 'Griffin'];
```

### Examples:

```
if(my_array_search($namesArray, 'Glenn Quagmire')){
   echo 'There is'; // Glenn
} else {
   echo 'There is not';
}

// optionally:
if(($retval = my_array_search($namesArray, 'Peter Griffin'))){
   echo 'There is';
   print_r($retval); // Peter, Griffin.
} else {
   echo 'There is not';
}
```

Now `$retval` is optional, it captures an array of matching subjects. This works because if the `$matches` variable in `my_array_search` is empty, it returns false instead of an empty array.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked like I wanted after changing the locations of the `$haystack` and `$needle` variables.

Comment: @MertS.Kaplan Aah yes, I'll update the code as well.

Answer (score 3):

Explode your string and then check, if there are any same strings in both arrays.

```
$namesArray = array('Peter', 'Joe', 'Glenn', 'Cleveland');
if (array_intersect(explode(' ', 'Peter Parker'), $namesArray))
    echo "There is.";
else
    echo "There is not.";
```

Comment: Thanks for the acceptable and simple solution. I think @Xorifelse's solution is better.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Regular Expressions - [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) ('i' means case insensitive) to check if array contains some words

for example:

```
$namesArray = array('Peter One', 'Other Peter', 'Glenn', 'Cleveland');
$check = false;

foreach($namesArray as $name) 
{
    if (preg_match("/.*peter.*/i", $name)) {
        $check = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($check) 
{
    echo "There is.";
}
else {
    echo "There is not.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. `preg_match` is a good method, but it would be better if there is no loop.